# Dropdown com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava procurando por um menu dropdown com jQuery e encontrei esse exemplo:

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5scvk154/)

Ele abre e fecha normal quando clico fora do menu ou em algum item dele, menos quando abro outro dropdown.

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes mudar a lógica um bocado para garantir que ele procura os outros *dropdown* e não só o próprio.

Poderia ser assim:

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5scvk154/1/))

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    $('.dropdown-menu').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var dropdown = $this.prev('.dropdown');
        if (dropdown[0] == target) $(this).toggle();
        else $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.btn-group > .dropdown-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    min-width: 160px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-group > .dropdown-menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="dropdown">Select</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="dropdown">Select</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            $('.dropdown-content').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var dropdown = $this.prev('.dropdown');
                if (dropdown[0] == target) $(this).toggle();
                else $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<style>
    .btn-group {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

    .btn-group+.btn-group {
        margin-left: 16px;
    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown-content {
        list-style-type: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 4px 0;
        margin-top: 3px;
        min-width: 160px;
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 7px;
        max-height: 350px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown-content li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;

    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown-content li a:hover {
        background-color: #f8f9fa;
    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown {
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown::after {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: 0.255em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        vertical-align: 0.255em;
        content: "";
        border-top: 0.3em solid;
        border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;
    }

    .btn-group>.dropdown:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="dropdown">Select</div>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Action 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="dropdown">Select</div>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```